# HTML E-Mail - the propper way

Tags: html, email

I want to send an e-mail containing HTML. I found dozens of tutorials or questions here on stack overflow on how to do it. But each one either omits some parts, contradicts another or is simply wrong. I am not searching for something with obscure style tags but rather the basic stuff. Let's take a table with some cells, colored cell-background, bold and italic text and some links. No images, no external content, no complicated CSS magic. Let's take this table as an example:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro

So the question is now: **How to write a *fully correct* HTML e-mail?**

I will use PHP to create and send the mail, but a solution should be valid for the general case.

This breaks down in several sub-questions:

1. Should it be a multipart e-mail which also contains a text-only part? What gives the better compatility?
2. What header needs to/should be added? `MIME-Version:`, `Content-type:`?
3. What about the body itself? Do we need the `<html ...>` tag? Is the `<!DOCTYPE ...` needed if the doctype is already in the header?
4. Do we need the `<head>` section? What should be there?
5. HTML, XHTML? Which version of it?
6. In the body: how should we set the table properties ? CSS in the head or as attributes?
7. What about the links? Do we need to encode them somehow if they contain special characters liks `?&=` or worse.

Comment: Including a text-only part is probably advisable since many people configure their E-Mail server to reject HTML-only mails (part of spam protection).

Comment: Thanks to some very poor decisions at Microsoft - desktop Outlook uses the **MS Word** document rendering code for displaying HTML e-mail messages instead of Trident - this *boneheaded* change was made in Outlook 2007 and hasn't changed since (whereas Outlook 97 through Outlook 2003 uses the systemwide Trident codebase and so renders HTML email better than Outlook 2016, this is insane!), which means you cannot use any CSS3 features and most of CSS2's layout features are implemented poorly. This has set back HTML by over a decade now.

Comment: (The official reason for this change was because, apparently, some users were complaining that HTML emails they composed in Word 2003 looked different in Outlook 2003 - so they decided to cripple Outlook's HTML capabilities instead of fixing Word's... smooth)

Comment: @flyx thanks. I did not know that. Are there any other reasons agains HTML only? I am targeting a heterogenic user base, also considering webmail (like gmail), thunderbird, android, mobile .. etc.

Comment: @Dai interesting. I also ran into other problems with Outlook. Like, it did not even recognize the mail to be HTML and displaying the source code. Do you have any examples on how a "perfect" HTML Mail for Outlook would look like?